# Update the hidden input every time the 1st one is updated

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a registration form. The SQL DB requires to type password 2 times, I want to replace it, in one, every time I put values in the 1st input the second input to update automatically. My code works ok if it's like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" id="pass1" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password2" id="pass2" />
</div>
```

I've tried this method, but shows me the error message "Please fill all required fields"

```
<div class='row'>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" id="pass1" />
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="Password" name="password2" id="pass2" />
</div>
```

How can I make it work, any tips?

Comment: What's the point of checking if you filled in your password correct if you only need to fill it in 1 time?!

Comment: Couldn't you *not* try and side-step this security measure and simply have your users confirm their password?

Comment: @Naruto this are the requirements from the client

Comment: How do you update the second password field?

Comment: The answer submitted by BeatAlex will do the trick, but I seriously think you've misunderstood your clients requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you could do something like this:

```
var $pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1"),
    $pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2");

$pass1.oninput = function() {
    $pass2.value = this.value;
}
```

But honestly, you should make them type it out twice really. What if their password isn't correct?

It will end up looking like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
    var $pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1"),
    $pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2");

    $pass1.oninput = function() {
        $pass2.value = this.value;
    }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="pass1" id="pass1">
<input type="text" name="pass2" id="pass2">
```

If you're using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pass1").on("input", function(){
      $("#pass2").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: this is only for a quick registration form, where you type only username, pass and email.

Comment: It's ultimately up to you, but I think this is a very bad idea. @ValeriCrudu

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me say very clearly: you should **not** be doing this, it's best to just have users confirm the password.

However, if you really must, the change can be made in JavaScript, but I recommend using the backend (assuming it's PHP/MySQL based on your question tag).

Simply insert the same password field into both DB fields, for example your HTML can be:

```
<div class='row'>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" id="pass1" />
</div>
```

And your query like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (..., `password1`, `password2`, ...) VALUES (..., $password1, $password1, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery equivalent:

```
$("#pass1").blur(function() {
    $("#pass2").val($(this).val());
};
```

As mentioned in comments and others answers, not recommanded to not let a person type his passwords 2 times..